# Cocoa 3D ios library iOS 6, 7 support

Tags: cocoa, ios6, ios7

I am planning to develop 3D application. I checked many 3D engines and libraries like Unity 3D, Marmalade, NinevehGL etc.

Cocoa 3D looks good and support Collada objects as well.

I checked there website http://brenwill.com/2011/cocos3d-development-roadmap/ but can't find anywhere they specifies, whether they support iOS 7.

If any body knows please suggest.

Answer (score 0):

For Anybody interested in same question i got Cocos3D guys reply and they very much support latest iOS. Also they keep on working on it. I am using it for me latest project.